# Ceridian Dayforce Integration with Active Directory

Tags: powershell, api, active-directory, azure-active-directory, integration

We are planning connect Microsoft Identity manager with Ceridian Dayforce HRIS tool. We want to use MIM then to sync with our Active Directory to get a list of all the users, roles and other details regularly.

I found Dayforce API documentation online here https://usconfigr58.dayforcehcm.com/api/ddn/swagger/

Can I use PowerShell to query and parse rest API so that I can get the information from Dayforce to our Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you could, you would write Powershell scripts to query the APIs using the the endpoints stated in Swagger to query the information you want, then use the resulting objects to update whatever you wanted to in AD. In Powershell the easiest way to do it would be using `invoke-restmethod` then use the appropriate Powershell AD commands to update the adusers mainly `set-aduser`

However, if you are using MIM, then you wouldn't be using Powershell to do it, you would use mim's workflow and rest connector functionality. Otherwise what's the point of using MiM if you are going to basically write your own sync?

Comment: In addition, you can look at this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/ceridiandayforcehcm-tutorial

Comment: Note there is no private messaging capability in Stack Overflow. Although users are allowed to offer to contact each other using off-site comms channels, we try to discourage that if possible, since we want help to be public. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to generate Q&A artefacts that help other developers in future, and we find that users very rarely come back to update their material based on off-site discussions.

Comment: good note, thanks halfer. it's just sometimes the questions are not detailed enough or the answers end up being an entire project. and in those cases, it doesn't necessarily make sense to have a discussion about architecture and design options in public like that.